# Assign reference of object by assignment operator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a question about the program below. In controller, the saveContact function: if I change line `ContactService.save($scope.newcontact);` to `$scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);`

It seems that the program works the same. I would like to know if the reason is that when this line `($scope.contacts = ContactService.list();` get executed, the reference of contact list in the service is assigned to `$scope.contacts` so that push new contact to `$scope.contacts` is same as push new contact to the contact list in the service?

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ContactController">
    <form class="well">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="newcontact.name" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="newcontact.email" />
        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="newcontact.phone" />
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" ng-model="newcontact.id" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="saveContact()" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
                <td>{{ contact.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ contact.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ contact.phone }}</td>
                <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="edit(contact.id)">edit</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="delete(contact.id)">delete</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.service('ContactService', function () {
    //to create unique contact id
    var uid = 1;

    //contacts array to hold list of all contacts
    var contacts = [{
        id: 0,
        'name': 'Viral',
            'email': 'hello@gmail.com',
            'phone': '123-2343-44'
    }];

    //save method create a new contact if not already exists
    //else update the existing object
    this.save = function (contact) {
        if (contact.id == null) {
            //if this is new contact, add it in contacts array
            contact.id = uid++;
            contacts.push(contact);
        } else {
            //for existing contact, find this contact using id
            //and update it.
            for (i in contacts) {
                if (contacts[i].id == contact.id) {
                    contacts[i] = contact;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    //simply search contacts list for given id
    //and returns the contact object if found
    this.get = function (id) {
        for (i in contacts) {
            if (contacts[i].id == id) {
                return contacts[i];
            }
        }

    }

    //iterate through contacts list and delete 
    //contact if found
    this.delete = function (id) {
        for (i in contacts) {
            if (contacts[i].id == id) {
                contacts.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //simply returns the contacts list
    this.list = function () {
        return contacts;
    }
});

module.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, ContactService) {

    $scope.contacts = ContactService.list();

    $scope.saveContact = function () {
        //ContactService.save($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact); ----change here
        $scope.newcontact = {};
    }


    $scope.delete = function (id) {

        ContactService.delete(id);
        if ($scope.newcontact.id == id) $scope.newcontact = {};
    }


    $scope.edit = function (id) {
        $scope.newcontact = angular.copy(ContactService.get(id));
    }
})
```

Link to [the original program.](https://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/72vT5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite the same. The array pointed to by `$scope.contacts` and the array used internally by `ContactsService` *are* the same array, but `ContactsService` is doing work in `save` that you are *not* doing by pushing directly on to `$scope.contacts`.

Specifically, if the contact you are adding is a *new* contact (one that doesn't have an id) then it adds an id for it. Additionally, `save` will update an existing contact.

Your change will appear to work because you are adding the contact to the `ContactsService` internal array, but you are bypassing the API the `ContactsService` has specified.

Your method could end up *duplicating* contacts in the list as well by indiscriminately adding them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If my understanding is correct, your mean when $scope.contacts = ContactService.list(); is executed, the reference of contact list in ContactsService(which is contacts) is assigned to the $scope.contacts. Am I correct?

Comment: @diane Yes, `ContactsService` is exposing an internal data structure (the list of contacts) to you via `list`. That same data structure is then added to the scope. In other words, the `contacts` variable inside `ContactsService` and `$scope.contacts` are the same object.